# Algorithm - Minimum items required per Set

Tags: algorithm, tree, set, logic, combinations

The user add the items in the cart and I need to give him the best combination of combos (sets) available for the items, so he can get the best possible price. If an item doesn't fit in a combo (set) there is no problem, he just won't get the discount in that item.
The big problem that I'm stuck is with the 'minimum quantity' of each set. I didn't found one algorithm example with it. That's tricky because while one set can provide the best price, but other 2 sets that could offer a better price together can be invalidated because they don't have the amount of items required to be OK.
I managed to loop through all possibilities but when there are more item it gets very slow. The problem:

**Each set has:**

- Minimum number of items required otherwise the set is invalid and can not be used
- Percentage discount
- Items that fit in this set (IDs)

**Example:**

```
Set 1 (min: 4, discount: 40%, acceptedIds: {1, 2, 4} )
Set 2 (min: 2, discount: 30%, acceptedIds: {2, 4, 5, 6} )
Set 3 (min: 3, discount: 25%, acceptedIds: {1, 2} )
Set 4 (min: 3, discount: 60%, acceptedIds: {4, 6} )
```

**Input**

```
itemsAddedInCart =
{ 
  (id: 1, price: 3), 
  (id: 1, price: 3), 
  (id: 2, price: 4), 
  (id: 4, price: 3), 
  (id: 5, price: 6), 
  (id: 6, price: 4)
}
```

Obs.: an insight that I had was to create a matrix with the discounts computed but didn't finished my logic. Example:

```
             Set 1            Set 2      ...
Item 1       $ 1.2            $ 0.6        
Item 2       ...              ...
...
```

If you don't understand something please let me know.

Comment: How many sets and how many items per set are you looking at?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur number of sets is >= 0, each set has its own minimum required and there isn't maximum, all items can be added in one if it's better